# Java. Join threads in order of completion and run a kind of a hook after each join

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to be able to join each thread at once it finished its job. In the code example below main thread will wait as long as each thread will run by their order in the list and only then next thread will be joined.

```
    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();

    threads.add(new Thread(new Worker(), "T1"));
    threads.add(new Thread(new Worker(), "T2"));
    threads.add(new Thread(new Worker(), "T3"));

    threads.forEach(Thread::start);

    threads.forEach(thread -> {
        try {
            thread.join();
            someHook();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Use a `CompletionService`.

Comment: What you're trying to do is better done with composable Futures.

Comment: You mean join each Thread separately, or join all altogether?

Comment: @pdem, separately. Let's say each thread does its own job, and after each job finished I want to consume that job result immediately. I don't want to wait 1st thread to finish when I already can use results of thread #5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `CompletableFuture`

```
    ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    ExecutorService single = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    List<CompletableFuture<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(new Worker(), e).thenRunAsync(this::someHook, single));
    futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(new Worker(), e).thenRunAsync(this::someHook, single));
    futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(new Worker(), e).thenRunAsync(this::someHook, single));

    futures.forEach(f -> f.get()); // try-catch left out for brevity
```

In this case you will run 3 tasks async and have a single thread force each hook to be done sequentially.

Comment: It may help developper coming from Javascript to notice that the completableFuture is like a Javascript "promise" implementation